# Audio level problems using a wireless hop

Tags: wireless, problems

I'm on a shoot where we need to use a wireless hop between mixer and camera. I'm using a sound devices 788t and have connected an audio limited tx2020 to one of the analogue outputs. The camera is a Sony DV cam with Audio Limited DX2020 connected to xlr input (line). The problem is the level on the camera is extremely low. When hardwired from 788 to camera, the level is good. I've tested the Audio Limiteds by plugging a lapel into the tx and pluging the dx into the camera xlr (mic). Levels are fine. Using the 788 to camera hop with mic selected on the cameras input gives a better level but theres tons of hiss and distortion.

Has anyone an idea to this problem? The outputs of the 788 are line level so the input on the camera should be line too even using the wireless hop right? So why the low level?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Have you checked the camera input settings for levels? There may be a manual adjustment you can make.

Comment: even when manual cam level is put to its maximum the signal is very low. When hard wired with xlr from 788s output, the level is good. It's only with the wireless hop that i have this issue. 

Comment: Reading the manual is a wonderful thing.

Answer (score 2):

The wireless hop is dropping the level well below line level.  There is nothing wrong with any of the kit. I suggest switching to a dedicated wireless monitoring system, they are very reliable.

http://www.sennheiser.co.uk/uk/home_en.nsf/root/professional_wireless-microphone-systems_monitoring_2000-series_021742

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the wireless receiver outputs a mic signal, not a line level signal. So if you take it in as a line level signal it's going to be very quiet.

You either need a line level transmitter/receiver pair or a good mic preamp between the receiver and the camera.

EDIT: Iain beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

some cameras including Sony, Panasonic and RED have a 10dB pad option in the menu somewhere that might be causing the problem. I couldn't tell you where to find it though, you might have to fiddle in the menu's, that if the camera op will let you anywhere near the menus!!

Comment: ive looked through the cams menu and it doesnt give many options. i think the problem lies with the line out of the 788 going into the input of the tx. though i cant find any solution. 

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your quick responses. Ok, on the tx2020s the gain knob is apparently split for mic and line levels. 1-4 is for mic, 5-8 for line. On the dx2020 cam feed i put the input to mic (dxs output mic level) and i put the gain on the tx to 8. The level is now good. The problem was apparently that the tx gain was set to mic level yet the 788s output is line level.

Thanks again to those who helped out.